# akka-http not showing metrics in NewRelic

Tags: sbt, akka, newrelic, sbt-native-packager, akka-http

I'm trying to monitor my akka-http Rest web-service with NewRelic

The application has only one **GET url** (defined with akka-http)

I have the following configuration in the **plugins.sbt**

```
logLevel := Level.Warn
addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbt" % "sbt-native-packager" % "1.0.4")
addSbtPlugin("com.gilt.sbt" % "sbt-newrelic" % "0.1.4")
```

I have the following configuration in the **build.sbt**

```
scalaVersion := "2.11.7"
name := "recommender-api"

...blablabla...

libraryDependencies += "com.typesafe.akka" % "akka-actor_2.11" % "2.4.2"
libraryDependencies += "com.typesafe.akka" % "akka-http-experimental_2.11" % "2.4.2"
libraryDependencies += "com.typesafe.akka" % "akka-http-spray-json-experimental_2.11" % "2.4.2"
libraryDependencies += "com.typesafe.akka" % "akka-slf4j_2.11" % "2.4.2"

newrelicIncludeApi := true
newrelicAppName := name.toString
enablePlugins(JavaServerAppPackaging, UniversalDeployPlugin, NewRelic)
```

I compile (and deploy) the code with **sbt universal:publish**, it creates a .zip, inside the .zip there is an executable file.

I pass the newRelic licenceKey by enviroment (NEW_RELIC_LICENSE_KEY)

The program starts and all works fine, the newRelic key is found (because the log dosen't say that it didn't find the key)

The aplication apears in the newRelic monitor system with the correct name

**BUT NewRelic dosen't show any metrics**

**what I have to do to see some metrics on NewRelic?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I realy don't know what I did to make it work, the changes I made were:

In the build.sbt

```
newrelicVersion := "3.26.1"
newrelicAppName := "recommenders-jobs-api-monitor"
```

In the plugin.sbt

```
addSbtPlugin("com.gilt.sbt" % "sbt-newrelic" % "0.1.5")
```

(I updated de sbt-newrelic version)
(I harcoded the name of the new relic app)
(I specified the version of the Java Agent)

Answer (score 1):

When you specify the value of `newrelicAppName` as `name.toString`, you are not doing what you expect.

`name` is a value of type `sbt.SettingKey`, this contains details of a setting's name, type, and a short description of what the key is used for.

The type that actually contains a value is an `sbt.Setting`. You can get a `Setting` from a `SettingKey` (in the current project and configuration) by calling the `.value` method.

---

So when you set the value like this:

```
newrelicAppName := name.toString
```

the value looks something like this:

```
$ show newrelicAppName
[info] sbt.SettingKey$$anon$4@54ec2887
```

Yes, that is actually a string containing lots of strange characters.

---

On the other hand, if you used the `.value` call:

```
newrelicAppName := name.value
```

the value then looks like:

```
$ show newrelicAppName
[info] my-project
```

---

My best guess is that New Relic doesn't like application names with strange characters (like dollar signs and ampersands). By setting a more normal string, you made it more likely that New Relic would accept such a name as input.

*Note:* the default value for `newrelicAppName` is the name for the containing project, so not setting the value at all in the first example would probably have "just worked" as you would have liked.

Comment: Hi @Gary, this is exactly what happened when I looked in new relic. There was a strange name with dolar signs, I suspected that the name was not being correctly taken. Despite that, the application was present in new relic, but with no metrics.

Comment: That agrees with my hypothesis then; if it had been `name.value` instead of `name`, all would have been good!