# Is there an easy way to provide akka-http some metrics?

Tags: scala, monitoring, akka-http

I wonder if there is an easy way to have a sort a monitoring like NewRelic or even an endpoint to have metrics on my akka-http based server (number of queries per minute, average response time, stats by endpoint, number of 404s, etc...)

My current akka-http server version is 10.0.0 and I use scala 2.11.8

Thanks for your help

Comment: I used kamon.io for spary and Akka actors. It supports different backends to send metrics. Here are some examples https://github.com/kamon-io/kamon-akka-http. You only need to start kamon before start your server. It uses AspectJ.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are many ways. If you need NewRelic, there is an sbt plugin for that: https://github.com/gilt/sbt-newrelic

It will work with akka-http as well, but be careful: [akka-http not showing metrics in NewRelic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35930515/akka-http-not-showing-metrics-in-newrelic)

And there is also kamon integration
https://github.com/kamon-io/kamon-akka-http

For manual metrics, you could try: https://github.com/Backline/akka-http-metrics